# Keras MNIST Gradient Descent Stuck / Learning Very Slowly

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'am training a simple MLP to classify MNIST digits using Keras. I'm encountering a problem where no matter what optimizer and learning rate I use, the model will not learn/descent and my accuracy stays pretty much as good as a random guess.

Here's the code:

```
model2=Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(output_dim=512, input_dim=784, activation='relu', name='dense1', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2, name='dropout1'))
model2.add(Dense(output_dim=512, input_dim=512, activation='relu', name='dense2', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2, name='dropout2'))
model2.add(Dense(output_dim=10, input_dim=512, activation='softmax', name='dense3', kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
model2.compile(optimizer=Adagrad(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.summary()
model2.fit(image_train.as_matrix(),img_keras_lb,batch_size=128,epochs = 100)
```

and the output:

```
Epoch 1/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 5s - loss: 14.6704 - acc: 0.0894     
Epoch 2/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 3/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 4/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 5/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 6/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 7/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 8/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 9/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 10/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 11/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 12/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 13/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 14/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 15/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 16/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 17/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 18/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 19/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 20/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 21/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892     
Epoch 22/100
33600/33600 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 14.6809 - acc: 0.0892
```

As you can see, the model isn't learning anything. I've also tried SGD, Adam, RMSprop, as well as decreasing the batch size to 32, 16, etc.

Any pointers as to why this is happening is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a `ReLU` activation which basically cuts off the activations below 0, and using a default `random_normal` initialisation which has the parameters `keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)` by default. As you can see, the initialisation values are very close to 0 and half of them (-.05 to 0) don't get activated at all. And the ones that do get activated (0 to 0.05) propagate the gradients very very slowly.

My guess is to change the initialisation to be around `0` and `n` (which is the operating range for ReLUs) and your model should converge quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not converging is because you need to tune the model's hyper-parameters using cross-validation. For example, for the Adagrad optimizer, try setting the learning rate to 1e-3 instead of the default 1e-2 e.g. :

```
model2.compile(optimizer=Adagrad(1e-3), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And you will see that the model will start learning better. Also, initialization and dropout rate play a factor and need to be tuned as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to normalize ur training data by dividing it by 255, it should do the trick